# Remove forward-slash using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have a text file that contains following

```
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc.git
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc.git/
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc
```

When I run the following command,

```
reponame=$(echo $url | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sed -e 's/.git\/$//' | sed -e 's/.git//')
echo $reponame
```

I am supposed to get

> abc

It fails for the lines ending in `.git/` but it works for the other 2 cases.

Comment: What's the desired output for above mentioned 3 lines ?

Comment: abc for each case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove the trailing slash before you print the last field with awk. Otherwise the last field will be empty.

Use

```
echo "$url" | sed -e 's#/$##' -e 's/\.git$//' | awk -F / '{print $NF}'
```

or even

```
echo "$url" | sed -e 's#/$##' -e 's/\.git$//' -e 's#^.*/##'
```

Tips:

- You can give several `sed` commands to one invocation of sed so it is sometimes not necessary to pipe from `sed` to `sed`. Either `sed -e 'cmd1' -e 'cmd2' ...` or `sed 'cmd1;cmd2;...'` will work.
- You can use a different delimiter for the `s` command of `sed` so you do not have to escape slashes in the pattern (I used `#` as a delimiter).

Comment: I tried the first one and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming all your lines in a file either have .git extension**

**ALSO SOLUTION IS GIVEN WITHOUT SED**

```
SHW@SHW:/tmp/abc # cat a
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc.git
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc.git/
https://git.centos.org/git/rpms/abc
SHW@SHW:/tmp/abc # cat a | while read line; do basename $line .git; done
abc
abc
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the *field separator* of the `awk`command. Change the order, first the `sed` commands, than the `awk`command:

```
reponame=$(echo $url |  sed -e 's/.git\/$//' | sed -e 's/.git//' | awk -F/ '{print $NF}')
echo $reponame
```

Comment: I not no output with this.

Comment: @SudhanshAggarwal: sorry, there was a typo, the closing bracket was on the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -E -e '\%(\.git|/)$%d' -e 's%.*/%%' file
abc
```

The `sed` script above first removes all lines from the input that ends with either `/` or the string `.git`.  It then strips off everything from the remaining lines up to and including the last `/`.

Since the text we are dealing with contains `/`, we're using `%` as an alternative delimiter in the `sed` expressions.

If you want to extract `abc` from each line in the file:

```
$ sed -E -e 's%\.git/?$%%g' -e 's%.*/%%' file
abc
abc
abc
```

This first removes the string `.git` (possibly followed by a `/`) from the end of each line of input before applying the same substitution as in the first `sed` command.